# threadirqs and kthreadd_task crash

Tags: linux

I am trying to enable "threadirqs" option on 3.10.12 linux kernel and my kernel crashes with null pointer access. The code flow to crash is this:

```
[    0.000000] Call Trace:
[    0.000000] [<8005544c>] wake_up_process+0xc/0x48
[    0.000000] [<8004c1b8>] kthread_create_on_node+0x64/0xc4
[    0.000000] [<8006d338>] __setup_irq+0x130/0x634
[    0.000000] [<8006d89c>] setup_irq+0x60/0xb4
[    0.000000] [<8050267c>] icu_of_init+0x1f8/0x2f8
[    0.000000] [<80517b30>] of_irq_init+0x2c8/0x304
[    0.000000] [<805007bc>] start_kernel+0x218/0x3a4
```

The crash happens because kthreadd_task is NULL inside wake_up_process. But as far as i see, kthreadd_task is initialized in start_kernel --> rest_init function which is much later than setting up interrupts ( init_IRQ ):

```
kthreadd_task = find_task_by_pid_ns(pid, &init_pid_ns);
```

So my question is, how are systems working which enabled "threadirqs" command line option enabled ( the code flow seems similar even on 3.17 kernel )

Thanks for any help